# Malloc fails to allocate memory of 1 GiB on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, malloc

I am trying to allocate memory of 1 GiB using `malloc()` on Windows and it fails. I know `malloc`'s uncertainty. What is best solution to allocate memory of 1 GiB?

Comment: Why are you using `malloc()` in C++?  Are you using Win32 or Win64?

Comment: Remember that `malloc` allocate a *contiguous* chunk of memory, and if there's no block big enough the allocation will fail.

Comment: Yeah I need 1 gb, trying to load a dump of size 1gb into memory, I am using Win64

Comment: On a 64-bit system (which have a big enough address-space) you could try to [memory.-map the file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file). For Windows read about [the `CreateFileMapping` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you're on a 32-bit system, you could read (or memory-map) parts of the file.

Comment: You may be on Win64 but what is the bitness of your application ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a 32-bit (x86) application, you are unlikely to be able to allocate a 1 GB continuous chunk of memory (and certainly can't allocate 2GB). As to why this happens, you should see the venerable presentation "Why Your Windows Game Won't Run In 2,147,352,576 Bytes" (Gamefest 2007) attached to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/16/windows-x64.aspx).

You should build your application as an x64 native (x64) application instead.

You could enable `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` and stick with a 32-bit application on Windows x64, but it has a number of quirks and may limit what kinds of 3rd party support libraries you can use. A better solution is to use x64 native if possible.

Comment: This is incorrect. The address space for Large Address Space - aware 32 bits apps is 4 GB on Windows 64.

Comment: As the presentation goes into great detail about, you can use LAA on 32-bit apps on Windows x64 to get 4 GB of memory space, but a much better solution is to use x64 native in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx%60) flag to tell Windows that you're not doing funny things with addresses. This unlocks an extra 2GB of address space on Win64.